# Extending an exponential valuation to the completion of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I was reading the section on *Completions* in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory.

Neukirch uses the term **multiplicative valuation** for what other authors seem to call **absolute value**. He uses the term **exponential valuation** for what other authors call **valuation**. Anyway, I will stick to his conventions.

On page 126 Neukirch mentions the following:

Let $v$ be an exponential valuation of a field $K$. Then $v$ is canonically continued to an exponential valutation $v^{\wedge}$ of the completion $K^{\wedge}$, by setting $v^{\wedge}(a) = \lim_{n \to \infty} v(a_n)$, where $a = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \in K^{\wedge}$, $a_n \in K$.

Perhaps this is obvious, but why does $\lim_{n \to \infty} v(a_n)$ exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n\rightarrow 0$ then clearly $v(a_n)\rightarrow \infty$, so let's exclude this case. This means that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $K$ with absolute value bounded above by $C$. Pick $N$ large enough so that for all $n\geq N$ $v(a_n-a_N)>C$. Now suppose $v(a_n)\neq v(a_N)$ for $n\geq N$. Since $v$ is a valuation it follows that $v(a_n-a_N)=\min(v(a_n),v(a_N))<C$. A contradiction!

So we've shown that for all $n\geq N$ $v(a_n)=v(a_N)$ i.e. the sequence $v(a_n)$ becomes constant after $N$.